# How to simplify interface initialization and push items

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I have created interface which contains other interface:

```
export interface Parent {
  childs: Child[];
}

export interface Child {
  key: string;
  value: string;
}
```

How can I simplify initialization and pushing items to that array? I already created:

```
methodName(): {
    let childs: Child [] = [];
    let parent = <Parent>{};
    for (field in fields...) {
      childs.push({key: field.name, value: field.value}) ///it does not matter
    }
    parent.childs = childs;
    return parent;
  }
```

but I think there is better way to do it but can not find solution.

Answer (score 1):

Use a `map`:

```js
const parent: Parent = {
  childs: fields.map((field) => ({ key: field.name, value: field.value }));
}
```

Comment: forgot parenthesis - `parent.childs = fields.map((field) => ({ key: field.name, value: field.value }))`

Comment: day's going well so far

Comment: Thanks for help. Maybe do you know how to iterate over FormControls of FormGroup?